# Maven: 'Package does not exist' (and other errors)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am running several selenium automated tests using Maven.  When I'm debugging in Eclipse, I usually just right click on testing.xml and Run As > TestNG Suite.  But running in Jenkins needs to be ran using `mvn test`.  But when I run that, I get several errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project ecom: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom/HelperMethods.java:[15,43] package com.company.automation.ecom.pages does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom/HelperMethods.java:[16,43] package com.company.automation.ecom.pages does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom/HelperMethods.java:[110,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Header
[ERROR] location: class com.company.automation.ecom.HelperMethods
[ERROR] /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom/HelperMethods.java:[110,62] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Header
[ERROR] location: class com.company.automation.ecom.HelperMethods
[ERROR] /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom/HelperMethods.java:[113,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SignIn
[ERROR] location: class com.company.automation.ecom.HelperMethods
[ERROR] /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom/HelperMethods.java:[113,58] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SignIn
[ERROR] location: class com.company.automation.ecom.HelperMethods
```

I know the files are present, when I run as TestNG suite everything works with no issues.  Additionally, when I run which `java -version` I get this:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

I know it's a configuration issue somewhere, but I don't know enough about maven/java configuration to figure it out.  The files that Maven is telling me are gone are my files, and they are absolutely present.  Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>com.kirklands.automation.ecom.retry.MyTestListenerAdapter</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>com.kirklands.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>ecom</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Project Structure:

```
src/main/java
    {package com.company.automation.ecom}
        CreditCard.java
        HelperMethods.java
src/test/java
    {package com.company.automation.ecom.pages}
        Header.java
        SignIn.Java
        (etc...)
    {package com.company.automation.ecom.tests}
        HeaderTests.java
        (etc...)
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue when you run `mvn test` in your local environment?

Comment: Yeah.  if I run `mvn test` from the command line (in the same folder as my pom.xml file) OR if I right click on the project in eclipse and Run As > Maven Test, I get the same output.

Comment: You need to switch your maven-compiler-plugin to use source/target 1.8 for java. Default is 1.5. See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: Thanks very much, that solved one of my problems!  I now no longer get the message about switching to source 7 or higher to enable strings in cases.  But, I am still getting the `package does not exist` errors.

Comment: is `com.company.automation.ecom.pages` package in a different maven module?

Comment: I hate to be 'that guy'... what's a maven module?

Comment: Could you show your project structure?

Comment: Just added some of the project structure, indicating where the problem files are.  Hope this helps...

Comment: If I'm reading that project structure correctly, your source files (CreditCard.java, HelperMethod.java) are in `src/main/java`, but should be in `src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom`

Comment: @kroe761 is your issue solved?

Comment: @nazar_art - Could you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510682/maven-package-does-not-exist-for-enum ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like your issue appears due to fact that you trying to access from your:

> src/main/java

Test sources - which are located:

> src/test/java

Here is the exact snippet of the log you posted:

> /Users/kroe761/Documents/workspace/ecom/src/main/java/com/company/automation/ecom/HelperMethods.java:[15,43] package com.company.automation.ecom.pages does not exist

It will work from another side: if you will use your sources (`src/main/java`) from test scope (`src/test/java`).

Maven has his own [lifecycle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

It has a ***strict consequence***:

- `compile` - compile the source code of the project
- `test` - test the compiled source code using a suitable unit testing framework. These tests should not require the code be packaged or deployed

And during `compile` you can compile only your sources. However, it depends on your tests (pages package), which can't be compiled at this moment, because it will compile only at `test` phase.
Thus ***compilation fails***.

For solving try to change your project structure, a little bit:

```
src/main/java
    {package com.company.automation.ecom}
        CreditCard.java
        HelperMethods.java
    {package com.company.automation.ecom.pages}
        Header.java
        SignIn.Java
        (etc...)
src/test/java
    {package com.company.automation.ecom.tests}
        HeaderTests.java
```

And your tests should use sources (core & pages) without any problem.

Comment: Yes, that does appear to have solved it.  Thanks for the maven clarification as well!

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'd prefer not to move the classes in Main into the test folder just for this purpose. Any other suggestions ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510682/maven-package-does-not-exist-for-enum

Comment: @testerjoe2 You asking me about suggestion and at the same time, I don't see any support for existing answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `maven clean install` command first.

That command will compile your `missing` package and it will even run the tests.

UPDATE: You should change your `com.company.automation.ecom.pages` package to your `src/main/java` folder. so that it can be compiled in `maven compile` phase.

Comment: I tried running `mvn clean install` but I got the same error.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I'd prefer not to move the classes in Main into the test folder just for this purpose. Any other suggestions ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510682/maven-package-does-not-exist-for-enum